# UISearchBarDelegate and textFieldShouldClear alternative

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

UITextFieldDelegate has a method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` which gets called when that little `x` icon is clicked by the user.

I couldn't find something similar for `UISearchBar` or `UISearchBarDelegate`. Is there another way to find out if that button / icon has been clicked inside a `UISearchBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
searchBar:textDidChange:
```

which according to the [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is also called when the X is pressed to clear the field.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (and note the Discussion sentence):

```
searchBar:textDidChange:
Tells the delegate that the user changed the search text.

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
Parameters
searchBar
The search bar that is being edited.
searchText
The current text in the search text field.
Discussion
This method is also invoked when text is cleared from the search text field.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
UISearchBar.h
```